# Using AWStats for multiple VHosts - 404 on perl file

Tags: apache, perl, centos7, web-hosting

I have a server setup using Centos 7 and the Centos Web Panel, I am using this to host several different domains.

I want to enable AWStats for the domains, I have managed to install AWStats, I've added `awstats.[domain].conf` files for all the domains and I've setup cron jobs to  process the logs.

I am now trying to allow each domain to see only their own data, I tried to add the awstats.pl file to their html folder:

```
/home/[user]/public_html/stats/awstats.pl
```

But calling this via `http://[domain]/stats/awstats.pl` gives me a 404 error.

I've also tried the following locations, all of which give the same 404 error:

```
/home/[user]/public_html/cgi-bin/awstats.pl
/home/[user]/public_html/stats/cgi-bin/awstats.pl
/home/[user]/public_html/awstats.pl
```

an example of one of my vhosts files is below:

```xml
<VirtualHost [localserverip]:80>
    ServerName [domain]
    ServerAlias www.[domain]
    ServerAdmin webmaster@[domain]
    DocumentRoot /home/[user]/public_html
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/[user]/public_html/cgi-bin/

    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/[domain].bytes bytes
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/[domain].log combined
    ErrorLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/[domain].error.log

    # Custom settings are loaded below this line (if any exist)
    # IncludeOptional "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/[user]/[domain]/*.conf"

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS=on
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir disabled
        UserDir enabled [user]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup [user] [user]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup [user] [user]
        suPHP_ConfigPath /home/[user]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid [user] [user]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID [user] [user]
    </IfModule>

    <Directory "/home/[user]/public_html">
        Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm sure there's a misconfiguration with the cgi-bin somewhere but I'm not really familiar with how this works, can anyone see why I can't load the awstats file?

Comment: It looks like `/home/[user]` and `/home/[domain]` are two different paths in your setup and only the former is published in the parts you have provided. If your problem would have to do with CGI, you would either get some 500 error code or plain text served or such. I guess you really simply don't serve `/home/[domain]/public_html` for some reason.

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning Sorry I made an error when replacing values, the only paths under `/home` are the users name (`[user]`), I have updated the question.

Comment: What I said regarding CGI still applies in my opinion. Add some simply text file, image or whatever in `[...]/public_html` and in `[...]/public_html/stats` and see if you still get the 404 by requesting both. Use individual names. Additionally tell us if some part of your path is a symlink, which you don't seem to allow by purpose.  Not sure if `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` overrides `-FollowSymLinks`, don't think so.

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning I added some test files to the folder and discovered they wouldn't serve either, checking the logs it turned out there was an unrelated error in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use perl at all, you can get ALL of the exact same functionality with Node.js with absolutely NO setbacks at all.

You're welcome.

Comment: Can you elaborate?